# How to move Ubuntu Server to SSD on Pi 4?

Tags: server

I have installed Ubuntu server on a Pi 4 and this works fine. But I now want to move it to an SSD as I’ve purchased an Argon One M2 case and an SSD

How do I do this?

The only instructions seem to require that I need to use Raspbian OS . Is this really the case? It seems to require that I update the Pi boot eprom. Can I do this from Ubuntu?

When I installed Ubuntu Server I got no options on how to partition the disk and I assume this is because it is a microSD, but with the SSD can I change this?

Although I used to be a Unix admin it is many years ago and I’m struggling to do thins from the command line. For example, I cant remember how to partition the disk from the command line anymore.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are too many questions in this.  The initial question, you need to configure the Pi using Raspbian unless you can find the needed scripts ported to your version of Ubuntu.  Given the stack of microSD cards I have laying around, its easier to swap out different OS with different cards to do the task.  This question might be better suited on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If I had any microSD cards lying around that might be an option but I don't

Answer (score 0):

I had used Raspeberry Pi Imager to install ubuntu server on ssd card . i used an adaptor to connect to my pc an then with raspberry pi imager i had procced the install , the same way that you can install on sdcard . it works just fine . You need the script for the fan  - https://gitlab.com/DarkElvenAngel/argononed ! This one is workin with ubuntu 22.04 server . i`m using it right now .

Comment: At the time I posted I had neither a caddy for the SSD nor a cable to connect the Argon base to my main PC. eventually I got both and did whar you suggested. But I then made the mistake of trying to resize the partition on the SSD using software on my PC. That resulted in the Pi booting from the SSD but I got an error "Access Denied" when  I tried to login using Putty.

Comment: I'm afraid I then forgot about it after that.

Comment: How do you suggest sorting out the partition size and can I download the Argon script without doing the build/make process?